# Limactl: How to fix chown problems?

Tags: docker, chown

I tried running this docker compose file
https://docs.sorry-cypress.dev/guide/dashboard-and-api

I used the docker template

```bash
limactl start --name=docker template://docker
```

With the following mounts inside the docker template

```yaml
mounts:
- location: "~"
  writable: true
```

When I run

```bash
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.minio.yml up
```

I get

```
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/Users/me/code/cypress/data/data-mongo-cypress': 
chown /Users/me/code/cypress/data/data-mongo-cypress: permission denied
```

When I run it with sudo, the first issue is bypassed but then I get this error from the mongo container

```
cypress-mongo-1          | chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Permission denied
```

I tried setting the chmod of Users/me/code/cypress/data/ to 0777 but it doesn't change anything

How to overcome these chown problems?

```
System
MACOS 13 Ventura
```

Comment: Have you tried running the container in privileged mode? (add privileged: true to the docker-compose.yml) You can also try running it as a specific user. More info can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Comment: @Bets it didn't help unfortunately, I got the same error. I also tried running it as another user but whatever I put in there, it doesn't have sufficient permissions to change the chown of the volume dir

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the [github issues](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/issues/231#issuecomment-1316683864)

I edited my lima instance like this

```bash
limactl edit docker
```

Then changed the `mountType` and the `mounts` props like this

```yaml
mountType: "9p"
mounts:
- location: "~"
  writable: true
  9p: 
    securityModel: mapped-xattr
    cache: "mmap"
```